# Identify the Page that Submitted the Form to the Current Page?

Tags: php, html, forms

There are two pages (say page1 and page2) in my project that can submit a form to a third page. 
I need to assemble the third page differently with PHP based on which of these two pages submitted the form.

Q. In the context of the third page (navigated from page1 or page2), how can I identify which page (out of page1 and pag2 ) submitted the form?

Comment: Use an `isset()` and add a reference key for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HTTP Referer but this can be unreliable since it is controlled by the client. Browsers can be configured to not send a referer, in which case your form will break.

The most reliable option is to explicitly send the current page in a hidden field in your form. You can get the name of the current page like this:

```
$current_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Then, in your HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="last_page" value="<?php echo $current_page; ?>">
```

If you're worried about users modifying the hidden field, you can store this value in a session variable instead.

Comment: `<?=` assuming OP has short open tags set/on of course ;) Some are not aware of those. Otherwise OP would need to do `<?php echo`.

Comment: How would the $_POST value for the page be? The whole URL of the sender page? I mean, the value the receiver page will get in the $_POST array.

Comment: I tested it and found out it is the name of the sender page's filename. Thanks /u/nullability for the great answer :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right, updated the answer just in case.

Comment: Cool. You could have just made an additional note about it :) short tags are cleaner to use though ;) cheers

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` shows you previous page. So if you submit a form you can catch it now

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` then you can use `parse_url` to analyze all URL parts